# How can I generate a PDF of the dashboardBody of a shinydashboard?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a dashboard written in R using the `shiny` and `shinydashboard` packages. Such a dashboard consists of a header, sidebar, and body. Here is a minimalistic example:

```r
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
  body = dashboardBody(h2("This goes into the PDF."))
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = function(input, output) {})
```

I would like to export the body of the dashboard into PDF. That is actually the default action when printing the dashboard opened in Safari.

However, I would like to programmatically export the body of the dashboard into PDF. How can I write such a function in R or Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem sometime ago and found out that if you open your app via browser, when printing using the browser tools, it would print only the body, as requested.